# Find the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}-(1-x)^\frac{1}{8} }{x}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate the following limit

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}-(1-x)^\frac{1}{8} }{x}$$

If we use the binomial expansion of the numerator term, the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$. The same answer is obtained if we apply L'Hospital's rule.

Is it possible to solve this using something even more basic ? i.e. without recourse to binomial expansion or L'Hospital's rule *or definition of derivative* ? The reason I ask this is because this problem (from a textbook) comes up before the introduction of L'Hospital's rule.

---

user37238 wanted to know how the binomial expansion can be used.Basically, we have

$(1+x)^n= 1 + nx + \frac{n (n-1)}{2} + \frac{n (n-1)(n-2)}{2!} + \ldots$

Similarly,

$(1-x)^n= 1 - nx + \frac{n (n-1)}{2} - \frac{n (n-1)(n-2)}{2!} + \ldots$

Using these expansions with $n=\frac{1}{8}$ in the given problem gives the answer.

Comment: Could you explain the solution with binomial expansion, please.

Comment: Here's another one: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cdot\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+i}-\sqrt[n]{1-i}}i\cdot n$$ Enjoy! :-)

Comment: @user37238 I have edited the question and added the binomial expansion solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, use
\begin{align}
&\;\;\;\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}-(1-x)^\frac{1}{8}}{x}=\\&=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{4}-(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}}{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{8}}=\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{2}-(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}}{\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{8}\right]\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{4}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}\right]}=\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{(1+x)-(1-x)}{\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{8}\right]\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{4}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}\right]\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{2}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}=\\
&=\frac{2}{\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{8}\right]\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{4}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}\right]\left[(1+x)^\frac{1}{2}+(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}.
\end{align}
Now to compute the limit, it suffices to set $x=0$ in the last expression.

Comment: And setting $x=0$, where do you arrive using the last expression ? Cheers.

Comment: I apologize ! I forgot the denominator meanwhile ! I just feel stupid. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No problem!

Comment: I think this one comes closest to OP's request for no use of derivative, LHospital, or binomial expansion. Just basic factoring is involved (+1).

Comment: @O.L. Whoa ! How is the result obtained from the last step ? The numerator is $2x$. If we divide the denominator by $x$, we *somehow* obtain 8 !!

Comment: @curryage It cancels with the numerator of the last line of my post.

Comment: @O.L. I don't understand. The numerator is $2x$. If we divide the denominator by $x$ and take the limit, how do we get the answer ?

Comment: @curryage I've updated the post, does it become more clear now?

Comment: @O.L. D'oh! I completely forgot the $x$ in the denominator. Apologies for the question.

Comment: @O.L. I was not the only one !!

Answer (score 4):

Written in the form $2\cdot \frac{(1+x)^\frac18-(1-x)^\frac18}{2x},$ the expression is twice the difference quotient for the derivative at $t=1$ of $f(t)=t^{1/8}.$ It's actually a "symmetric" difference quotient, which for a differentiable function will approach the usual derivative. So the limit is $2\cdot f'(1)=\frac14.$

Note that then this problem could be done just from the definition of the derivative, provided one is OK with using the symmetric difference quotient, and so does not involve L'Hospital or binomial expansion.

Comment: Probably the most elegant solution here, nicely done.

Comment: @coffeemath Nice ! but the derivative had not been introduced at this point.

Comment: @orion It remains to explain how to calculate the derivatives before learning about the limits.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}-(1-x)^\frac{1}{8} }{x} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}-1+1-(1-x)^\frac{1}{8} }{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{8}-1 }{x}+\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1-x)^\frac{1}{8}-1 }{-x}=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4} $$

We applied the known limit for $a\in R$:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^a-1 }{x}=a $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

When $x$ is small compared to $1$, $(1+x)^n \simeq 1+nx$. This is a property you must remember.

I am sure that you can take from here.